# Refined manipulation of sympy expressions

Tags: python, expression, sympy

I am trying to work with sympy and work with manipulation of expressions.

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import  t

x0,v0 = sym.symbols("x0 v0 ",  real=True)
wn = sym.symbols("omega_n",  positive = True, real=True)
z = sym.symbols("zeta",  positive = True, real=True)

x = sym.Function('x')
Dx = sym.Derivative(x(t), t)
Dx2= sym.Derivative(x(t), t,2)

res = sym.dsolve(Dx2 +2*z*wn*Dx+ wn**2*x(t), x(t), 
   ics = {  x(0): x0, 
            Dx.subs(t,0):v0})
```

The above yields the following expression

[image]

The part circled in red can be further simplified to [image], however I can't figure out how is it possible to simplify selected portions of the expression.

If I take a simpler exampler `wn*x0*z**2/(2*wn*z**2-2*wn)` then its possible to cancel out the terms with simplify(), but I could find anywhere some good documentation on how to work and substitute parts of the equation.

---

Another similar issue is with the term [image], which I would like to transform to [image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use pattern matching. Note that your circled term is a multiplication, containing `z**2` (a power operation).

```py
# search the expression tree and select all multiplications
# containing a power with exponent 2
w = sym.Wild("w", properties=[
    lambda e: e.is_Mul and any(t.is_Pow and t.exp == 2 for t in e.args)
])
t = list(res.find(w))[0]
print(t)
# out: omega_n*x0*zeta**2/(2*omega_n*zeta**2 - 2*omega_n)

# Perform the simplification and substitution
res = res.subs(t, t.simplify())
```

Now let's look for the second term in your question:

```py
# loop over each exponential term and apply a
# powsimp to its argument.
for t in res.find(sym.exp):
    res = res.subs(t, sym.exp(t.args[0].powsimp()))
print(res)
```

Edit: similarly, you can apply the same technique to simplify the other square roots on your expression.

Comment: I was unaware of the "properties" aspect of Wild.

Comment: It is pretty powerful! :)

Comment: I generally use the predicates of the "properties" as the find-part of a `replace` call: `expr.replace(lambda e: e.is_Mul and any(t.is_Pow and t.exp == 2 for t in e.args), lambda e: simplify(e))`.

Answer (score 1):

First here is the `rhs` of your equation:

```
In [58]: res.rhs
Out[58]: 
                                                                 ⎛      _______   _______⎞   ⎛          2                _______   _______                         _______   _______⎞       ⎛       _______   _______⎞
⎛           x₀⋅ζ           x₀              v₀           ⎞  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠   ⎜   ωₙ⋅x₀⋅ζ       ωₙ⋅x₀⋅ζ⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1        ωₙ⋅x₀        v₀⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠
⎜- ───────────────────── + ── - ────────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                                + ⎜────────────── + ─────────────────────────── - ────────────── + ──────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                               
⎜      _______   _______   2           _______   _______⎟                                    ⎜      2                       2                      2                    2           ⎟                                 
⎝  2⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1         2⋅ωₙ⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠                                    ⎝2⋅ωₙ⋅ζ  - 2⋅ωₙ          2⋅ωₙ⋅ζ  - 2⋅ωₙ         2⋅ωₙ⋅ζ  - 2⋅ωₙ       2⋅ωₙ⋅ζ  - 2⋅ωₙ    ⎠
```

For the first part of your question what we can do is collect on `wn` for the `rhs` of the equation. This has the effect of cancelling out the `wn` in the terms where they can cancel:

```
In [45]: res.rhs.collect(wn)
Out[45]: 
                                                                 ⎛      _______   _______⎞   ⎛     2            _______   _______                   _______   _______⎞       ⎛       _______   _______⎞
⎛           x₀⋅ζ           x₀              v₀           ⎞  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠   ⎜ x₀⋅ζ      x₀⋅ζ⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1       x₀      v₀⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠
⎜- ───────────────────── + ── - ────────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                                + ⎜──────── + ──────────────────────── - ──────── + ──────────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                               
⎜      _______   _______   2           _______   _______⎟                                    ⎜   2                  2                  2              ⎛   2    ⎞     ⎟                                 
⎝  2⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1         2⋅ωₙ⋅╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠                                    ⎝2⋅ζ  - 2           2⋅ζ  - 2           2⋅ζ  - 2       ωₙ⋅⎝2⋅ζ  - 2⎠     ⎠
```

Now we see there are various powers that could be simplified by combining them. In general `sqrt(z-1)*sqrt(z+1)` is not necessarily equal to `sqrt(z**2 - 1)` but the assumption that `z` is positive means that they are equal. In that case `powsimp` should combine those powers:

```
In [46]: res.rhs.collect(wn).powsimp()
Out[46]: 
                                                                             ⎛                   ________                    ________⎞                                 
                                                 ⎛      _______   _______⎞   ⎜     2            ╱  2                        ╱  2     ⎟       ⎛       _______   _______⎞
⎛       x₀⋅ζ       x₀          v₀       ⎞  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠   ⎜ x₀⋅ζ      x₀⋅ζ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1       x₀      v₀⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱ ζ - 1 ⋅╲╱ ζ + 1 ⎠
⎜- ───────────── + ── - ────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                                + ⎜──────── + ──────────────── - ──────── + ──────────────⎟⋅ℯ                               
⎜       ________   2            ________⎟                                    ⎜   2              2              2          ⎛   2    ⎞ ⎟                                 
⎜      ╱  2                    ╱  2     ⎟                                    ⎝2⋅ζ  - 2       2⋅ζ  - 2       2⋅ζ  - 2   ωₙ⋅⎝2⋅ζ  - 2⎠ ⎠                                 
⎝  2⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1         2⋅ωₙ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
```

Here `powsimp` didn't apply to the exponents so we need to use `deep=True` to tell it to look deeper for things to combine:

```
In [47]: res.rhs.collect(wn).powsimp(deep=True)
Out[47]: 
                                                 ⎛       ________⎞   ⎛                   ________                    ________⎞       ⎛        ________⎞
                                                 ⎜      ╱  2     ⎟   ⎜     2            ╱  2                        ╱  2     ⎟       ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟
⎛       x₀⋅ζ       x₀          v₀       ⎞  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠   ⎜ x₀⋅ζ      x₀⋅ζ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1       x₀      v₀⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
⎜- ───────────── + ── - ────────────────⎟⋅ℯ                        + ⎜──────── + ──────────────── - ──────── + ──────────────⎟⋅ℯ                       
⎜       ________   2            ________⎟                            ⎜   2              2              2          ⎛   2    ⎞ ⎟                         
⎜      ╱  2                    ╱  2     ⎟                            ⎝2⋅ζ  - 2       2⋅ζ  - 2       2⋅ζ  - 2   ωₙ⋅⎝2⋅ζ  - 2⎠ ⎠                         
⎝  2⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1         2⋅ωₙ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
```

There are common factors like `2` that we can extract with `factor_terms`:

```
In [48]: factor_terms(res.rhs.collect(wn).powsimp(deep=True))
Out[48]: 
                                             ⎛       ________⎞                                                          ⎛        ________⎞
                                             ⎜      ╱  2     ⎟   ⎛    2                                         ⎞       ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟
⎛      x₀⋅ζ                 v₀      ⎞  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠   ⎜x₀⋅ζ         x₀⋅ζ        x₀           v₀      ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
⎜- ─────────── + x₀ - ──────────────⎟⋅ℯ                        + ⎜────── + ─────────── - ────── + ──────────────⎟⋅ℯ                       
⎜     ________              ________⎟                            ⎜ 2          ________    2             ________⎟                         
⎜    ╱  2                  ╱  2     ⎟                            ⎜ζ  - 1     ╱  2        ζ  - 1        ╱  2     ⎟                         
⎝  ╲╱  ζ  - 1         ωₙ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                            ⎝         ╲╱  ζ  - 1             ωₙ⋅╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                         
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                    2
```

Now we can collect on powers of `z**2 - 1` to reduce the repeating subexpressions:

```
In [55]: factor_terms(res.rhs.collect(wn).powsimp(deep=True)).collect(z**2 - 1)
Out[55]: 
⎛              v₀⎞        ⎛       ________⎞   ⎛                     v₀ ⎞       ⎛        ________⎞
⎜      -x₀⋅ζ - ──⎟        ⎜      ╱  2     ⎟   ⎜    2         x₀⋅ζ + ── ⎟       ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟
⎜              ωₙ⎟  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠   ⎜x₀⋅ζ  - x₀           ωₙ ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
⎜x₀ + ───────────⎟⋅ℯ                          ⎜────────── + ───────────⎟⋅ℯ                       
⎜        ________⎟                            ⎜   2            ________⎟                         
⎜       ╱  2     ⎟                            ⎜  ζ  - 1       ╱  2     ⎟                         
⎝     ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                            ⎝             ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                         
─────────────────────────────────────────── + ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     2                                                 2
```

Finally applying `factor_terms` to the coefficients of that last collect allows us to cancel the one remaining awkward term and normalise the minus signs:

```
In [56]: factor_terms(res.rhs.collect(wn).powsimp(deep=True)).collect(z**2 - 1, factor_terms)
Out[56]: 
⎛             v₀ ⎞        ⎛       ________⎞   ⎛             v₀ ⎞       ⎛        ________⎞
⎜      x₀⋅ζ + ── ⎟        ⎜      ╱  2     ⎟   ⎜      x₀⋅ζ + ── ⎟       ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟
⎜             ωₙ ⎟  -ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠   ⎜             ωₙ ⎟  ωₙ⋅t⋅⎝-ζ + ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠
⎜x₀ - ───────────⎟⋅ℯ                          ⎜x₀ + ───────────⎟⋅ℯ                       
⎜        ________⎟                            ⎜        ________⎟                         
⎜       ╱  2     ⎟                            ⎜       ╱  2     ⎟                         
⎝     ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                            ⎝     ╲╱  ζ  - 1 ⎠                         
─────────────────────────────────────────── + ───────────────────────────────────────────
                     2                                             2
```